# FTP File upload timeout

Tags: php, ftp

My filemanaging script keeps timing out on files greater than ~4 MB.

I am on shared hosting but have access to the php.ini file (though editing it does not seem to make a difference).

The php.ini file has been updated to take 100M (the goal max upload size), but is still reading as 8M via:

```
ini_get('upload_max_filesize')
```

I have a php.ini file in the root directory of the site with these settings:

```
upload_max_filesize = 104857600
post_max_size = 124857600
max_input_time = 480
max_execution_time = 480
memory_limit = 144857600
```

My host (godaddy) says they cannot restart the server (shared) and I should not need to in the first place, just upload the ini file. However none of my attempts have been able to resolve the problem.

I using PHP FTP functions. I am connecting, and files < ~5 MB upload with no trouble, but any larger than that and the page sits there for a few minutes (8 maybe? max_execution_time is set to 8 minutes) before the page changes to the upload.php script with a white page. No error messages, nothing.

Any help?

Comment: Tell GoDaddy to shove it if possible.  Off topic, but their CEO thought it was fun to slaughter an elephant.
http://ecocentric.blogs.time.com/2011/03/30/shooting-an-elephant%E2%80%94why-godaddys-ceo-was-wrong/?hpt=T2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check if your new ini has been loaded with `phpinfo()`. If not, then you have found your problem.

Comment: I have been keeping an eye on that, and it is still at 8M

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I've only seen upload_max_filesize values of 10M format.  Not 104857600 unlabeled if that makes sense.  Also, I believe you do have to restart apache after you change the ini file.

Comment: I tried 100M with the same result. The integer 104857600 is in bytes (the default expected), and equals 100 MB.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I just haven't seen it personally.